# how to use both fixed and relative position property in same page using css?

Tags: html, css

I am using 3 divisions (Div) in a page, The first div is fixed on top of the page.

The second and third div are placed one by one order below the first div.

The problem is when i am using fixed position in first div mean the second div is comes automatically above the first div, i need second div to placed at bottom of first div.

And when i am scrolling the page the first should be in same place(top of page) and other two div's should scroll up behind first one.

here below the my current code.

```
<div id="first" style="position: fixed; height: 100px; width:100%;">asdfgh</div>
<div id="second" style="position: relative; height: 500px; width:100%;">zxcvbn</div>
<div id="third" style="position: relative; height: 200px; width:100%;">qwerty</div>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`?

Comment: The second div comes with dynamic content using php. the height of the second div is not fixed that's why i added php.

Comment: Sorry, but that is totally irrelevant. Please remove that tag.

Comment: Thank You, PHP has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

HTML:

```
<div id="first">asdfgh</div>
<div id="second">zxcvbn</div>
<div id="third">qwerty</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto; /* Ensure this is specified or you need padding-top and not margin-top on #second */
}

#first
{
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: borderbox; /* You need this if #first have borders */
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100; /* This is needed to put the #first in front of other elements */
}

#second
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#third
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="demo_wrapper" class="toFixed">
    <div id="wrapped1">asdfgh</div>
    <div id="wrapped2">zxcvbn</div>
    <div id="wrapped3">qwerty</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto; /* Ensure this is specified or you need padding-top and not margin-top on #second */
}

/** Switch from and to fixed with CSS class (JS needed) **/

#demo_wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

#wrapped1
{
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}

#wrapped2
{
    background: yellow;
    height: 460px;
}

#wrapped3
{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 80px;
}

.toFixed>div:first-child
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100; /* This is needed to put the #first in front of other elements */
}

.toFixed>div:first-child+div
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

This is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/583fR/) (switch commented part in HTML to see the two options).

Comment: Thank You, Is this work fine when i am opening this page in Mobile Phone and Tab without any alignment problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed divs acts like absolute position divs so you have to specify margin for your second div. Like:

```
<div id="first" style="position: fixed; height: 100px; width:100%;">asdfgh</div>
<div id="second" style="height: 500px; margin-top: 100px">zxcvbn</div>
<div id="third" style="height: 200px;">qwerty</div>
```

Div is automatically 100% width if it's static div.

Comment: Is any other source are there with out fixing margin-top: 100px; on second div?

Comment: Why you want another option?

Comment: Because when opening in Mobile Phone Or Tab mean this position may differ that's why i am asking you. if you have any other idea please tel me.

Comment: When you use pixels as height and margin values it does not matter what device you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="first" style="position: fixed; height: 100px; width: 100%; top: 0px;">asdfgh</div>
<div id="second" style="position: relative; height: 500px; width:100%; margin-top: 100px;">zxcvbn</div>
<div id="third" style="position: relative; height: 200px; width:100%;">qwerty</div>\
```

Is this what you want?